# Атрибут pattern поля input для проверки имени домена

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

Требуется регулярное выражение атрибута pattern для проверки поля input, где значением должно являться имя домена (включая кириллицу) любого уровня.
Пример проверки без учета кириллицы:

```
<input pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$">
```

Answer (score 2):

Плохо, что паттерны в теге input (как и регулярки в js) не понимают Юникод.

Вот такой вариант предлагаю в качестве решения:

```
^(?=[^_]+$)([\wа-яА-ЯёЁ]([\wа-яА-ЯёЁ-]*[\wа-яА-ЯёЁ])*\.)+(?=[^\d]+$)[\wа-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,63}$
```

Для сокращения записи использую метасимвол `\w`, который заменяет набор символов `[a-zA-Z\d_]`;

конструкция `(?=[^_]+$)` нужна, чтобы исключить знак подчеркивания из доступных символов (он входит в `\w`);

`(?=[^\d]+$)` - исключает дополнительно и цифры из домена верхнего уровня

```html
<form >
  Введите имя домена без http://: 
  <input type="text" name="homepage" pattern="^(?=[^_]+$)([\wа-яА-ЯёЁ]([\wа-яА-ЯёЁ-]*[\wа-яА-ЯёЁ])*\.)+(?=[^\d]+$)[\wа-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,63}$" required><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**UPD** Хотя можно и так:

```
^([a-zA-Z\dа-яА-ЯёЁ]([a-zA-Z\dа-яА-ЯёЁ-]*[a-zA-Z\dа-яА-ЯёЁ])*\.)+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,63}$
```

Длиннее только на 1 символ :)

**UPD2** А негативный просмотр вперед дает самую короткую регулярку:

```
^(?!.*_)([\wа-яА-ЯёЁ]([\wа-яА-ЯёЁ-]*[\wа-яА-ЯёЁ])*\.)+(?!.*\d)[\wа-яА-ЯёЁ]{2,63}$
```